# How viable would it be for all women to be telepathic?

Tags: society, alternate-reality, telepathy

Supposing that telepathy is possible in the first place, how possible would it be for our current world to exist given that all women are telepathic, and men don't know this.

- How would this societal state be maintained?
- What would it imply about men's perception of society?
- Why aren't women completely dominant in society?

Note: For the moment let's ignore the non-binariness of biological gender, and all the complexities implied by those who don't identify with their biological gender.

Let's just say that approximately half of all people are telepaths from birth. The other half don't know it. The telepathic half are not visibly in control and are, if anything, slightly less prioritised. And that in broad generality each person could identify whether the another person was telepathic, if they knew that telepathy existed.

Comment: As a general rule, any question that's asking after the implications of X across *all of society* is going to be too broad by half.

Comment: Welcome to [Worldbuilding.SE]. [Click here to learn more about our culture](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) and please read our meta posts about [high concept questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868) and [open-ended questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6654), which tend to be too subjective and broad. Also, it would take 4 seconds for men to discover women were telepathic, most likely because the odds are in my favor that out of the world's 3.5 billion women, one of them can't keep the secret.

Comment: Oh, though closed, let me suggest a point of view.  How viable is it?  Perfectly viable.  Society would develop from the stone ages to account for the female ability.  What you're doing is making the mistake of thinking that our current society is in any way a starting point for that comparison.  It isn't.  That society would develop very, very differently from our present-day adventure (and the question of how is too broad, too.  Basically, that's your novel).

Comment: Adding to what @JBH has offered, you might want to explore how and why the mass mind of all women might influence that very different society such that the ignorant males believed they were living in the real world society which we currently live in.  You can have your alternate-timeline present and it can be very similar to our real world but that would require a vast conspiracy on the part of the telepaths.

Comment: My issue with this question is not that it's too broad; I suspect it's not a world building question as I'm convinced I'm living in this world already. In point of fact, this scenario explains far too much of my real life for comfort and I'm going to start keeping a careful eye on half of those around me, watching for the clues.

Comment: ...half the population has telepathy, and the other half *doesn't know it*?  Completely breaks suspension of disbelief, there would be too many scenarios where those with would share the knowledge with those without, from accidental slip of the tongue to vying for leverage or authority to personal loyalty or love.  There might be scenarios which limit the knowledge in one soceity, maybe, kinda, sorta, with handwaving aplenty and suspiciously specific scenarios, but it's going to be impossible to make any kind of a clean division.